# Autopick items from inventory when emptying stack in hand

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I want to setup a Bukkit server for Minecraft and I wonder whether there is any multiplayer plugin which automatically "refills" your equipped item stack if possible. That is, assume you build something and are out of wood, but if you got another stack in your inventory it will automatically be placed in your hands so you can work on seamlessly.

Comment: It definitely exists, the [tekkit pack](http://www.technicpack.net/tekkit/) has a plugin like this. Too bad I don't know exactly which one you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mod to do this, but it's not a Bukkit plugin. [Inventory Tweaks](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/323444-inventory-tweaks-143b-aug-21/) is a client-side mod that works in multiplayer as well (it's used by the client-side install of Tekkit, for example.) It will automatically refill your hotbar items when they empty/break, among other things:

> - It automatically replaces your tools as they break, and item stacks once emptied
> - It sorts your inventory and your chests in a single click/keystroke
> - It provides lots of powerful shortcuts to move items around
> - It allows you to customize entirely the way your inventory is sorted, thanks to clever configuration files

Since it's client-side, you and your players will have to install it individually.